# Idiomatically using PreparedStatements in the Vertx Cassandra client?

Tags: vert.x

The documentation for the Vert.x Cassandra client is here: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-cassandra-client/java/

To generate prepared statements the example uses the following snippet of code:

```
cassandraClient.prepare("SELECT * FROM my_keyspace.my_table where my_key = ? ", preparedStatementResult -> {
  if (preparedStatementResult.succeeded()) {
    System.out.println("The query has successfully been prepared");
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = preparedStatementResult.result();
    // now you can use this PreparedStatement object for the next queries
  } else {
    System.out.println("Unable to prepare the query");
    preparedStatementResult.cause().printStackTrace();
  }
});
```

This is not directly useful, since the PreparedStatement is now retrieved inside the callback while it would be used outside the callback in the methods of the class, where the prepared statement is created. In other words, we would have something like:

```
public final MyClass {

    private PreparedStatement query;

    public MyClass(Vertx vertx) {
        client = CassandraClient.create(vertx, options);

        client.prepare("SELECT * FROM my_keyspace.my_table where my_key = ? ", preparedStatementResult -> {
            if (preparedStatementResult.succeeded()) {
                query = preparedStatementResult.result();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unable to prepare the query");
                preparedStatementResult.cause().printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public Foo foo() {
        // Uses the prepared statement "query" here.
    }
}
```

Now you can't call the method `foo()` before the callback in which the prepared statement is returned has been called.

The solution I have is an initialization method that returns a `Completable`. The way it's been hooked up into the rest of the initialization is a bit ugly. How are folks setting up these prepared statements? I couldn't find any nice examples on GitHub either.

Comment: I cover how to get around callback code in my course at udemy if you want more in depth -- https://www.udemy.com/course/backend-development-with-vertx/?referralCode=063C2D57CCB957C5088C

Answer (score 0):

That is just how callback based programming is. Everything needs to keep getting nested in so that you can access response objects of callbacks.

There are 3 main ways of going about it

1. RxJava - compose flows as operators
2. Java/Vert.x futures
3. Kotlin coroutines

My suggestion is to use kotlin with coroutines - that way you can write regular style code where things get returned and can be used below [as opposed to inside callbacks] - while still keeping the call it self nonblocking and async

In your case it would become `val ps = client.prepare().await()` - then you can just use `ps` as normal